# Hugo server - The term 'hugo' is not recognized

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-code, hugo

I'm working in Microsoft Visual Code (first ever time).

I'm trying to build a site using the academic theme following these steps https://www.dsquintana.blog/create-an-academic-website-free-easy-2020/

After installing Hugo Extended `scoop install git go hugo-extended`

I run the next steps: Now open up a new terminal window in Visual Studio Code by clicking on the "Terminal menu" and then "New Terminal". Type in the following command in the Terminal window: `hugo server`

I get this message

```
hugo : The term 'hugo' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if  
a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ hugo server
+ ~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (hugo:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

Hugo is located: C:\Users\CHRIS\scoop\apps\hugo-extended

Website is: C:\Users\CHRIS\OneDrive\Website\Website\starter-academic.github\starter-academic>

Do I need to move the Hugo folder or add a path? If so, how do I add the path/folders?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I installed hugo with winget and it also updated the path but still it does not recognize hugo in terminal

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error means that Powershell is not aware where `Hugo` is installed. There is a system setting, `PATH`, that defines in which directories Powershell (and CMD shell) do look for executables. Since Powershell doesn't know Hugo's location, it will give the error you've encountered.

Now, there are a few solutions:

1. Add Hugo to path
2. Use absolute path
3. Set an alias

Adding Hugo's directory to system-wide path makes sense in some cases. The steps are well-documented in, say, [Superuser answer](https://superuser.com/q/949560). Usually this is not the best way, since path has maximum length, and it's not a best practice to stuff a lot of things there.

Using absolute path means that instead of `hugo server`, one does `& "C:\Users\CHRIS\scoop\apps\hugo-extended\hugo" server`. The amperstand `&` is call operator and tells Powershell to execute the quoted string.

Setting an alias will introduce a new command that is an alias to existing program or command. For Hugo, you might do `set-alias -name hugo C:\Users\CHRIS\scoop\apps\hugo-extended\hugo`. When you type hugo into the same Powershell prompt, Powershell knows that hugo is an alias that points into the executable's actual location.

Setting an alias can be done via a script, or saving its definition in [Powershell profile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_profiles?view=powershell-7.1).

Answer (score 1):

If you installed hugo-extended with scoop, it should automatically be on your path. I recommend that you close all open VS Code terminals (by clicking the "Kill Terminal" trash can icon) and exit VS Code. Then relaunch VS Code, open a New Terminal, and run:

```
hugo version
```

If `hugo` is not on your path now, let us know.

I've written about scoop and hugo in [Scoop: A Windows Package Manager (Featuring Hugo & Figlet Examples)](https://www.ii.com/scoop-windows-package-manager/) -- maybe there is some useful info in my article...